# Are devices with kernels below 3.6 vulnerable to CVE-2016-5696?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, android

Today I was reading about the potential impact of CVE-2016-5696 in Android phones running Linux 3.6+ and though my phone has 3.4 I checked the value of `net.ipv4.tcp_challenge_ack_limit` and it is also 100, as it is in my OpenVZ VPS running kernel 2.6.32.

My question is, what does exactly determine if a system is vulnerable apart from that parameter? Has it been widely backported to older kernel versions?

Answer (score 0):

It should affect only Android version 4.4 or higher. According to http://www.heise.de/newsticker/meldung/HTTP-Verbindungen-von-einer-Milliarde-Android-Geraeten-angreifbar-3300328.html one can check if one is vulnerable if sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_challenge_ack_limit gives a value back that is less than 1000, so your device is vulnerable.

Comment: I'm actually running Marshmallow with monthly security patches (CM13).

Comment: CM is another thing. If it is affected, expect updates shortly. The bug was introduced in kernel 3.06. Redhat backported it https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2016-5696 . If it was backported by CM, you would need to ask them, or just wait a little bit and it will resolve itself.